# While exporting excel file through wenzhixin bootstrap table some columns are right aligned and some are left aligned

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel, bootstrap-table

While exporting excel file through ***wenzhixin bootstrap table*** some columns are ***right-aligned*** and some are ***left-aligned*** as shown in the below image.

[image]

Please suggest me how to rectify this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is because Excel uses the comma character to group by thousands (ie, every third integer in the value). Therefore it doesn't recognise your values with commas every second digit as correctly formatted floating point numbers, so it instead displays them as string. As such they are left aligned. Any value recognised as a valid floating point number is right aligned.

To simple way to fix this is to remove the extra comma characters (`,`) from the values. For example, `9,99,99,999.00` would become `99,999,999.00` or `99999999.00`.

That being said Excel does support lakh/crores grouping, as can be seen [here](https://www.excelrush.com/display-numbers-in-lakhs-and-crores/), however you need to explicitly set the format on the cell. It will not happen by default. It's down to the Excel export library you're using whether or not it allows you to specify the cell formatting prior to export.